# Select exact match first in doctrine query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I need to write a query in query builder in Symfony 3.4. It have to order by exact match. For example I have 3 rows with column name which has:
"test", "test 1", "test1" and when I search for string "text" the order is:

```
1. test
2. test1
3. test 1
```

In mysql it worked with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE col LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY INSTR(col,'test') asc, col asc;
```

I've tried to use functions LOCATE and INSTR in my query builder, but I got error:

```
Attempted to call function "LOCATE" from namespace "AppBundle\Repository".
```

This is my query:

```
$qb->select('c.id')
                ->from($this->_entityName, 'c')
                ->where('c.name LIKE :searchTerm')
                ->orderBy(LOCATE($searchTerm, 'c.name'), $sortDirection)
                ->groupBy('c.id')
                ->setParameter('searchTerm', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
```

EDIT: I solved this.

```
->orderBy(LOCATE($searchTerm, 'c.name'), $sortDirection)
```

to

```
->orderBy('LOCATE(:searchTermLocate, c.name)', $sortDirection)
->setParameter('searchTermLocate', $searchTerm)
```

But now I have problem with polish characters. When polish character appear this result is return at first or last place depending on sort direction. For example when $searchTerm is "czapka" the results are:

```
1. pod czapką
2. czapka
3. czapka z daszkiem
4. czapka zimowa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [native query](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) or ["Additional DQL functions for Doctrine2"](https://github.com/IAkumaI/doctrine-functions).